# Is there an equivalent of tf.lite.Interpreter.get_input_details for C++?

Tags: python, c++, python-3.x, tensorflow, tensorflow-lite

In TensorFlow lite's Python API, there are methods to retrieve details concerning the input and output tensors, called `tf.lite.Interpreter.get_input_details` and `tf.lite.Interpreter.get_output_details`. I am after the 'quantization' entry in these dicts, which contain a value for mean and standard deviation each.

When deploying these models on another platform, I use the C++ API to set up an interpreter. To prepare the inputs for my model, I also need mean and standard deviation.

I was unable to find equivalents of these functions in C++. Do they exist?

Comment: The short answer is no. But you can reshape input and output tensors in C++.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the quantization parameter out of `TfLiteTensor` structure, like...

```
// Get the input tensor indices.
const std::vector<int>& inputs = interpreter->inputs();
// Get the tensor object of the 1st input.
TfLiteTensor* tensor = interpreter->tensor(input[0]);
const TfLiteQuantizationParams& params = tensor->param
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also fetch the same information using `PrintInterpreterState()`, in fact quite overwhelming:

```
tflite::PrintInterpreterState(interpreter.get());
```